# get DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks older than a day

Tags: c#, datetime

I am saving images with unique names. To get unique name I used `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`. Now I want to delete all images older than a day. How can I get the ticks older than a day? 
I have mapped time with ticks.

```
1:52:14.312 PM - 633614215343125000
1:52:14.359 PM - 633614215343593750
1:52:14.421 PM - 633614215344218750
1:52:14.468 PM - 633614215344687500
1:52:14.515 PM - 633614215998593750
```

What is the best way to get ticks older than a day? OR how to get the ticks of 24 hours ago?

Comment: What `1:52:14.312 PM` represents exactly? I would say `TimeSpan` but it has `PM` designator.

Comment: How many ticks in a day? Subtract that from the current tick val, and that should give you the cutoff point. Anything less than that is older than a day.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1).Ticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes `Ticks` as parameter. Extract ticks from file name, parse them to `long` and create a `DateTime` type object. Later you can select records older than a day.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(633614215998593750);
```

To select dates older than a day use:

```
if(dt <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`TimeSpan.TicksPerDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticksperday(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the ticks per day, so just subtract that from your current ticks to get the ticks 24 hours ago e.g:

```
var ticks24HoursAgo = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ticks);

if (DateTime.Now - dt > TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
    {
       //do something
    }
```

Also - you can work with UTC instead of local

Answer (score 0):

Every DateTime object has a Ticks property, so just get 24 hours ago (add -1 days to DateTime.Now should be sufficient), and then delete all of the values that are less than the ticks of your calculated time.